# Python Scraping Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, web-scraping

I'm attempting to scrape weather data from weatherunderground and using the multiprocessing.dummy library to run my requests through different threads.  I'm getting an error when running the following code and I was wondering whether someone could walk me through what's going on and a possible solution.  Note: my code could be wildly off.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # HTML Text Parsing Package
from urllib2 import urlopen # Package to read URLs
import requests # Package to actually request URL
import nltk
import re
import itertools as ite
import pandas as pd
def scrape(urls):
    actual_temp = []
    string = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(string)
    actual_temp_tag = soup.find_all(class_ = "wx-value")[0]
    actual_temp.append(actual_temp_tag.string)
    return actual_temp

URLs = []
for j in range(1,2):
    for i in range(1,32):
        SUB_URL = 'http://www.wunderground.com/history/airport/KBOS/2014/' + str(j) + '/' + str(i) + '/' + '/DailyHistory.html'
        URLs.append(SUB_URL)


from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool

pool = ThreadPool(8)
results = pool.map(scrape, URLs)

pool.close()
pool.join()
```

The following is the error message I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\bwei\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "C:\Users\bwei\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 558, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()
```

In addition once my program has executed, how do I close all of the threads?  I noticed that after trying my % of available memory goes up but doesn't go back down after running

Comment: What's the error you are getting?..Post the `Traceback` message

Comment: Just added the error message to the question

Comment: `string = requests.get(URL)` `requests.get` returns a response object, not a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't pass `string`, the `requests.models.Response` object, to `BeautifulSoup`. Pass `string.contents` instead:

```
In [124]: type(string)
Out[124]: requests.models.Response

In [120]: BeautifulSoup(string)
TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

In [126]: soup = BeautifulSoup(string.content)
```

---

Also, your `scrape` function refers to `URL`, which should have been a NameError since it is not defined. Instead pass the argument `url` to `requests.get`:

```
def scrape(url):
    actual_temp = []
    string = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(string.content)
    actual_temp_tag = soup.find_all(class_ = "wx-value")[0]
    actual_temp.append(actual_temp_tag.string)
    return actual_temp
```

Comment: I also have one more question.  Naturally when I run this code my % of available memory goes up.  However after I finish and close the pool it doesn't actually go down.  Is there a way to close the threads after I'm done with the code?

Comment: [The memory may not returned to the operating system](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/why-doesnt-python-release-the-memory-when-i-delete-a-large-object.htm) until the python process is terminated. If you wrap all your present code in a function, you can use `multiprocessing.Process` to run that function in a separate process. Then it can return the result to the main process *and* terminate the subprocess, thus returning the memory consumed by the subprocess to the operating system.

Comment: Would you have any tips on making this run even faster?  Does increasing the threadpool have a linear relationship with time to run or are there diminshing returns?

Comment: The main bottleneck is network communication speed. Increasing the number of threads may help -- but be careful to respect wunderground's terms of service and robot policy and be aware that if you pound a server too hard it may have a way of detecting that and throttle such users.